# How to extend errors based on quick-error?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have a crate `Lib1` that declares something like:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum MyError {
        Foo {
            description("FooError")
        }
    }
}
```

I have some another library `Lib2` that depends on `Lib1`.

I would like to extend this `MyError` with some additional errors that are specific to `Lib2`. That way I can reuse all the base errors that were declared in `Lib1`.

Btw, I have complete control on both libraries and I can modify them as much as I need to. I definitely would like to keep using `quick-error` for this. Is it possible to extend this somehow?

*Note: I already had a look at [Can I extend an enum with additional values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214064/can-i-extend-an-enum-with-additional-values) That was definitely something I knew about before opening the question. 
This does not solve this specific problem. Ideally I would like to keep using `quick_error`. Plus using composition for error makes error handling downstream very complicated. Is there a nice pattern for extending errors in libraries?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I extend an enum with additional values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214064/can-i-extend-an-enum-with-additional-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [Can I extend an enum with additional values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214064/can-i-extend-an-enum-with-additional-values), composition of other enums is possible and common practice for creating an extended sum type designated to errors. The same idea can be applied to error types created with `quick_error`, by passing other errors as the **cause** of your own type. Considering a hypothetical crate `lib2`:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;
extern crate lib2;

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum MyError {
        Foo {
            description("FooError")
        },
        Lib2(err: lib2::Error) {
            description("Failed to do something done by lib2")
            from() // derive `From<lib2::Error>`, very useful
            cause(err)
        }
    }
}
```

The `from()` clause makes the compiler derive `From<lib2::Error>` for `MyError`. This is particularly useful, as it makes raising a `Result<T, MyError>` on a `lib2` error as simple as employing the `?` operator.